# Wesbite scrolls despite overflow-y

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Please see the [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0nv2dx5o/).

The website scrolls entirely despite overflow-y configured onto the DIV of the orange area.
If the list within the orange area is shorter, it works perfectly: The website doesn't scroll, only a scrollbar appears on the right side of the area.
But if the inner content grows, there's a point that website begins to scroll.
How can I avoid that behavior? Doesn't matter how long the orange content is, only that area should scroll.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```
... links to fiddle must be accompanied by code...
```

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Maybe use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Until then I've voted to close this off topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping i understood you well.Try this using bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col ">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
        <div class="p-2 flex-even bd-highlight bg-primary" >Heading</div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-even bd-highlight bg-warning yellow">



        </div>
        <div class="p-2 flex-even bd-highlight bg-secondary">Flex item 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col bg-success Context">Context</div>
  </div>
```

Styling:

```
.row{
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .row >div{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 .Context{
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }

 .flex-even {
  height: 32.5vh;
}
.yellow{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Adjust the flex-even class in accordance to your height preference